# Object Not Deleting When Delete Method Is Used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D platformer game and I'm making it so objects are constantly going by and it's sussposed to delete the items when it touches an object offscreen. But it just goes past it and doesn't delete and both have a collider. And the thing I want to delete does have the tag.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionButterland : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Talking script;
    public GameObject pan;
    public bool Touching;
    public GameObject clone;
    public bool objectCreated = false;

    void Owie()
    {
        if (Touching == true)
        {
            script.Health -= 10;
            Debug.Log("Health decreased to " + script.Health);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Owie", 0.5f, 0.5f);
        InvokeRepeating("TrialOne", 0.9f, 0.9f);
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Delete"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Touching = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Touching = false;
    }

    void TrialOne()
    {
        if (script.trialone == true && !objectCreated)
        {
            clone = Instantiate(pan, new Vector3(10.16f, -2.44f, 0f), transform.rotation);
            clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-5, clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            objectCreated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that kinematic is the correct rigidbody for this entity?

Comment: I want the player to not be able to be able to move the objects

Comment: To have collisions/triggers you need Rigidbody2D on one of the two colliding objects. If you don't want it influenced by the built-in physics you need to set it as kinematic.

Comment: I know I set it to kinematic and that's the reason I did